# handle null value on a table for analysis

Tags: mysql, sql, analytics

I try to solve challenge using data set

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/thedevastator/global-video-game-sales

The question that I try to solve is:

The total worldwide sales revenue generated by each video game platform, grouped by year and sorted in descending order by year and then by total sales revenue.

My query:

```
SELECT 
    vgsales.year,
    vgsales.platform,
    SUM( vgsales.global_sales ) AS `Total Sales` 
FROM
    vgsales 
GROUP BY
    vgsales.platform, 
    vgsales.year
ORDER BY
    YEAR DESC,
    `Total Sales` DESC;
```

And here is the result:

```
| year | platform | Total sales         |
|------|----------|---------------------|
| N/A  | PS2      | 22,179999999999996  |
| N/A  | Wii      | 16,899999999999995  |
| N/A  | 2600     | 10,510000000000003  |
| N/A  | X360     | 10,349999999999998  |
| N/A  | PS3      | 8,49                |
| N/A  | XB       | 6,170000000000001   |
| N/A  | GBA      | 4,9399999999999995  |
| N/A  | PSP      | 4,569999999999999   |
| N/A  | PC       | 3,7699999999999996  |
| N/A  | DS       | 3,5299999999999994  |
| N/A  | PS       | 3,27                |
| N/A  | GC       | 2,2199999999999998  |
| N/A  | 3DS      | 1,18                |
| N/A  | GB       | 1,03                |
| N/A  | N64      | 0,67                |
| N/A  | PSV      | 0,3                 |
| 2020 | DS       | 0,29                |
| 2017 | PS4      | 0,03                |
| 2017 | PSV      | 0,02                |
| 2016 | PS4      | 39,25000000000002   |
| 2016 | XOne     | 12,369999999999987  |
| 2016 | 3DS      | 6,599999999999999   |
| 2016 | PSV      | 3,399999999999996   |
| 2016 | WiiU     | 3,2899999999999996  |
| 2016 | PC       | 2,5999999999999974  |
| 2016 | PS3      | 2,59                |
| 2016 | X360     | 0,8300000000000001  |
| 2015 | PS4      | 115,29999999999997  |
| 2015 | XOne     | 57,660000000000025  |
| 2015 | 3DS      | 26,99               |
| 2015 | PS3      | 18,220000000000002  |
| 2015 | WiiU     | 16,380000000000003  |
| 2015 | X360     | 13,049999999999999  |
| 2015 | PC       | 8,069999999999997   |
| 2015 | PSV      | 7,09999999999999    |
| 2015 | Wii      | 1,55                |
| 2015 | PSP      | 0,12000000000000001 |
| 2014 | PS4      | 98,76000000000003   |
| 2014 | XOne     | 52,43               |
| 2014 | PS3      | 50,96000000000002   |
| 2014 | 3DS      | 43,140000000000036  |
| 2014 | X360     | 36,41999999999998   |
| 2014 | WiiU     | 22,509999999999994  |
| 2014 | PSV      | 14,73999999999999   |
| 2014 | PC       | 13,389999999999993  |
| 2014 | Wii      | 4,439999999999999   |
| 2014 | PSP      | 0,24000000000000005 |
| 2014 | DS       | 0,02                |
| 2013 | PS3      | 117,38999999999994  |
| 2013 | X360     | 89,61000000000001   |
| 2013 | 3DS      | 55,88000000000002   |
| 2013 | PS4      | 24,760000000000005  |
| 2013 | WiiU     | 21,84               |
| 2013 | XOne     | 18,599999999999998  |
| 2013 | PC       | 12,829999999999995  |
| 2013 | PSV      | 12,690000000000001  |
| 2013 | Wii      | 9,359999999999998   |
| 2013 | PSP      | 3,189999999999996   |
| 2013 | DS       | 1,96                |
| 2012 | PS3      | 109,49000000000002  |
| 2012 | X360     | 100,87999999999992  |
| 2012 | 3DS      | 51,14000000000004   |
| 2012 | PC       | 23,53               |
| 2012 | Wii      | 22,770000000000003  |
| 2012 | PSV      | 18,530000000000005  |
| 2012 | WiiU     | 17,840000000000003  |
| 2012 | DS       | 11,639999999999993  |
| 2012 | PSP      | 7,71999999999999    |
| 2011 | PS3      | 159,3700000000001   |
| 2011 | X360     | 145,1200000000002   |
| 2011 | 3DS      | 62,53               |
| 2011 | Wii      | 62,41000000000001   |
| 2011 | PC       | 35,250000000000036  |
| 2011 | DS       | 27,799999999999994  |
| 2011 | PSP      | 17,89000000000001   |
| 2011 | PSV      | 5,1499999999999995  |
| 2011 | PS2      | 0,47                |
| 2010 | X360     | 171,05000000000004  |
| 2010 | PS3      | 144,42000000000007  |
| 2010 | Wii      | 131,8000000000001   |
| 2010 | DS       | 87,97999999999995   |
| 2010 | PSP      | 35,11000000000007   |
| 2010 | PC       | 24,460000000000004  |
| 2010 | PS2      | 5,629999999999995   |
| 2009 | Wii      | 210,4400000000002   |
| 2009 | PS3      | 132,33999999999997  |
| 2009 | DS       | 121,99000000000001  |
| 2009 | X360     | 120,85000000000001  |
| 2009 | PSP      | 38,070000000000036  |
| 2009 | PS2      | 26,45               |
| 2009 | PC       | 17,160000000000043  |
| 2008 | Wii      | 174,16              |
| 2008 | DS       | 147,89000000000047  |
| 2008 | X360     | 135,76000000000002  |
| 2008 | PS3      | 119,69000000000001  |
| 2008 | PS2      | 53,830000000000034  |
| 2008 | PSP      | 34,680000000000035  |
| 2008 | PC       | 12,669999999999975  |
| 2008 | XB       | 0,18                |
| 2008 | DC       | 0,04                |
| 2007 | Wii      | 154,96999999999997  |
| 2007 | DS       | 149,3600000000002   |
| 2007 | X360     | 95,83999999999993   |
| 2007 | PS2      | 76                  |
| 2007 | PS3      | 73,81000000000006   |
| 2007 | PSP      | 47,48000000000004   |
| 2007 | PC       | 9,399999999999984   |
| 2007 | GBA      | 3,4299999999999997  |
| 2007 | XB       | 0,5499999999999999  |
| 2007 | GC       | 0,27                |
| 2007 | DC       | 0,02                |
| 2006 | Wii      | 137,91000000000003  |
| 2006 | DS       | 121,14999999999998  |
| 2006 | PS2      | 103,41999999999999  |
| 2006 | PSP      | 55,850000000000044  |
| 2006 | X360     | 51,879999999999995  |
| 2006 | PS3      | 21,070000000000004  |
| 2006 | GC       | 11,29               |
| 2006 | XB       | 10,149999999999991  |
| 2006 | GBA      | 5,35                |
| 2006 | PC       | 2,969999999999998   |
| 2005 | PS2      | 160,65000000000012  |
| 2005 | DS       | 131,4000000000002   |
| 2005 | XB       | 49,17000000000011   |
| 2005 | PSP      | 44,23000000000001   |
| 2005 | GBA      | 33,90000000000001   |
| 2005 | GC       | 27,799999999999976  |
| 2005 | X360     | 8,319999999999999   |
| 2005 | PC       | 4,469999999999995   |
| 2004 | PS2      | 211,77999999999992  |
| 2004 | GBA      | 78,09               |
| 2004 | XB       | 65,50000000000001   |
| 2004 | GC       | 28,889999999999983  |
| 2004 | DS       | 17,459999999999994  |
| 2004 | PC       | 10,459999999999992  |
| 2004 | PSP      | 7,13                |
| 2003 | PS2      | 184,28999999999996  |
| 2003 | GBA      | 56,72999999999996   |
| 2003 | XB       | 55,16000000000003   |
| 2003 | GC       | 50,660000000000004  |
| 2003 | PC       | 8,959999999999988   |
| 2003 | PS       | 2,05                |
| 2002 | PS2      | 205,40000000000006  |
| 2002 | GBA      | 74,38               |
| 2002 | GC       | 51,93               |
| 2002 | XB       | 48,15000000000006   |
| 2002 | PC       | 8,599999999999996   |
| 2002 | PS       | 6,689999999999998   |
| 2002 | DC       | 0,29                |
| 2002 | N64      | 0,08                |
| 2001 | PS2      | 166,43000000000006  |
| 2001 | GBA      | 61,62000000000001   |
| 2001 | PS       | 35,520000000000024  |
| 2001 | GC       | 26,299999999999997  |
| 2001 | XB       | 22,23999999999999   |
| 2001 | GB       | 9,24                |
| 2001 | PC       | 5,51                |
| 2001 | N64      | 3,2600000000000002  |
| 2001 | DC       | 1,07                |
| 2001 | WS       | 0,28                |
| 2000 | PS       | 96,27999999999993   |
| 2000 | PS2      | 39,11000000000001   |
| 2000 | N64      | 34,00999999999999   |
| 2000 | GB       | 19,759999999999998  |
| 2000 | DC       | 5,989999999999998   |
| 2000 | PC       | 4,679999999999999   |
| 2000 | XB       | 0,99                |
| 2000 | WS       | 0,68                |
| 2000 | GBA      | 0,06                |
| 1999 | PS       | 144,5700000000001   |
| 1999 | N64      | 57,95999999999997   |
| 1999 | GB       | 38,010000000000005  |
| 1999 | DC       | 5,169999999999999   |
| 1999 | PC       | 4,749999999999999   |
| 1999 | WS       | 0,46                |
| 1999 | SNES     | 0,26                |
| 1999 | SAT      | 0,09                |
| 1998 | PS       | 169,58              |
| 1998 | N64      | 49,28000000000002   |
| 1998 | GB       | 26,9                |
| 1998 | SAT      | 3,819999999999999   |
| 1998 | DC       | 3,39                |
| 1998 | PC       | 3,2800000000000002  |
| 1998 | SNES     | 0,22000000000000003 |
| 1997 | PS       | 136,0799999999999   |
| 1997 | N64      | 39,509999999999984  |
| 1997 | PC       | 11,260000000000002  |
| 1997 | SAT      | 6,7700000000000005  |
| 1997 | GB       | 6,37                |
| 1997 | SNES     | 0,99                |
| 1996 | PS       | 94,67999999999999   |
| 1996 | GB       | 36,02               |
| 1996 | N64      | 34,10999999999999   |
| 1996 | SNES     | 15,929999999999996  |
| 1996 | PC       | 10,59               |
| 1996 | SAT      | 7,69                |
| 1996 | NG       | 0,1                 |
| 1996 | PCFX     | 0,03                |
| 1995 | PS       | 35,92000000000002   |
| 1995 | SNES     | 32,21000000000001   |
| 1995 | SAT      | 11,579999999999998  |
| 1995 | PC       | 4,2299999999999995  |
| 1995 | GB       | 3,5999999999999996  |
| 1995 | NG       | 0,33000000000000007 |
| 1995 | TG16     | 0,16                |
| 1995 | 3DO      | 0,08                |
| 1994 | SNES     | 35,08               |
| 1994 | PC       | 12,85               |
| 1994 | GB       | 12,170000000000002  |
| 1994 | GEN      | 8,109999999999998   |
| 1994 | PS       | 6,020000000000001   |
| 1994 | SAT      | 3,6400000000000006  |
| 1994 | NG       | 0,7999999999999999  |
| 1994 | SCD      | 0,37                |
| 1994 | NES      | 0,11                |
| 1994 | 3DO      | 0,02                |
| 1993 | SNES     | 40,010000000000005  |
| 1993 | NES      | 3,61                |
| 1993 | SCD      | 1,5                 |
| 1993 | GEN      | 0,6500000000000001  |
| 1993 | NG       | 0,21000000000000002 |
| 1992 | SNES     | 32,97999999999999   |
| 1992 | GB       | 25,48               |
| 1992 | GEN      | 12,66               |
| 1992 | PC       | 3,0199999999999996  |
| 1992 | NES      | 1,9800000000000002  |
| 1992 | GG       | 0,04                |
| 1991 | SNES     | 16,21               |
| 1991 | NES      | 6,11                |
| 1991 | GB       | 5,57                |
| 1991 | GEN      | 4,34                |
| 1990 | SNES     | 26,16               |
| 1990 | NES      | 15,74               |
| 1990 | GB       | 4,890000000000001   |
| 1990 | GEN      | 2,6                 |
| 1989 | GB       | 64,98               |
| 1989 | NES      | 7,849999999999999   |
| 1989 | 2600     | 0,62                |
| 1988 | NES      | 45,01               |
| 1988 | GB       | 1,43                |
| 1988 | 2600     | 0,75                |
| 1988 | PC       | 0,03                |
| 1987 | NES      | 19,759999999999998  |
| 1987 | 2600     | 1,9800000000000002  |
| 1986 | NES      | 36,410000000000004  |
| 1986 | 2600     | 0,6599999999999999  |
| 1985 | NES      | 53,44               |
| 1985 | 2600     | 0,45                |
| 1985 | PC       | 0,03                |
| 1985 | DS       | 0,02                |
| 1984 | NES      | 50,09000000000001   |
| 1984 | 2600     | 0,27                |
| 1983 | NES      | 10,959999999999999  |
| 1983 | 2600     | 5,83                |
| 1982 | 2600     | 28,859999999999996  |
| 1981 | 2600     | 35,77000000000001   |
| 1980 | 2600     | 11,379999999999999  |
```

My question is how to solve null value in this case? Should I change to a random/min/max year? If I fill the null column year is there any impact when an data analyst make an analyze report? What best method to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can add having condition

```
SELECT vgsales.year,
    vgsales.platform,
    SUM( vgsales.global_sales ) AS `Total Sales` 
FROM
    vgsales 
GROUP BY
    vgsales.platform, 
    vgsales.year
HAVING vgsales.year is not null
ORDER BY
    YEAR DESC,
    `Total Sales` DESC;
```